# Does GAE jdo not support identity strategy="timestamp"

Tags: java, google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore, jdo

I am trying to store timestamp as the key for my app's datastore on GAE. I see that timestamp is supported on [jdo platform](http://www.datanucleus.org/products/datanucleus/jdo/value_generation.html#timestamp) as IdGeneratorStrategy, but when I try to set the IdGeneratorStrategy on the key, I do not see a definition for timestamp.
[image]

I am using the latest GAE sdk, so I don't know if I missed something or is timestamp not supported on GAE as the datastore object key IdGeneratorStrategy?

Comment: how can something generate a Timestamp if you make the field have a type Key?

Comment: @BillyFrost - I added a picture to show what I mean. Having DataType of Key or Timestamp is not making any difference

Answer (score 1):

Use

```
@Persistent(customValueStrategy="timestamp", valueStrategy=IdGeneratorStrategy.UNSPECIFIED)
```

since it is not a JDO standard option